# Async task take to much time to load

Tags: android, twitter, android-asynctask

Hello i developed app for showing tweets in list..
I am getting all twitter ids from parse.com
Code for that.

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Twitter");

        ob = query.find();
        String[] strings = new String[ob.size()];
        // for (ParseObject imageupload : ob) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            ParseObject object = ob.get(i);

            strings[i] = object.getString("TwitterId");
            // images.add(map);
        }
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask(getActivity(), list, images, bar)
                    .execute(strings);
        }
```

And then i am passing array of twitter ids to async task

```
@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(final String... screenNames) {
    // String result = null;

    String rString[] = new String[screenNames.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < rString.length; i++) {
        rString[i] = getTwitterStream(screenNames[i]);
        //
    }
    return rString;
}

// onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an
// Array list of tweets
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    Twitter twitter = new Twitter();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        twitter.addAll(jsonToTwitter(result[i]));

        Collections.sort(twitter, new SimpleDate());

    }

    adapter = new StreamListAdapter(context, twitter);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

The problem is that the async task load tweets from all twitter ids and then it displayed in list..
I want to load some tweets and then display it while other tweets are loading in background

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be that you give only the first say 10 elements of the array. The AsyncTask loads it and publishes it in onPostExecute, then you call the asyncTask again with the next 10 elements, etc. Just don't start the asynctasks from a loop because the order of tweets could be unpredictable.

Another approach could be digging into the AsynTask class' onProgressUpdate and publishProgress.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29
I have not tried this but it might worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` can yield intermediate results : implement [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) and call [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) within `doInBackground`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the twitter API, but if you get each part of data in the for loop, you can use publishProgress:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rString.length; i++) {
        rString[i] = getTwitterStream(screenNames[i]);
        publishProgress(rString[i]);
    }
```

You receive the published String in onProgressUpdate, which is called on the main App thread:

```
 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     adapter.add(progress[0]);
 }
```

This way the new data will appear in the list as soon as you get it.

Comment: The method publishProgress(Void...) in the type AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Change Asynctasks middle generic argument to String instead of Void

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you notifyDataSetChanged after adding?